# Handshake failure with identical client hellos

Tags: tls

I'm at my wit's end investigating a handshake failure I'm receiving.

We have two separate clients using .Net + Server 2012 R2. Both are attempting a TLS handshake with the same destination IP. Wireshark shows the client hello as identical for both sides, but only one is successful. For the unsuccessful one, the server responds with a handshake failure (error code 40) immediately following the client hello.

I've done a diff comparison of the hex dump of the client hellos and the only noticeable differences are the timestamp and random.

Success:

[image: Success]

Failure:

[image: Failure]

What could be the problem at this point? Could it even be a TLS issue if there are no differences in the client hello? I haven't been able to find any resources that could explain this.

Even ideas at what to investigate will be helpful.

EDIT:
If other's run into this, the problem was network security software BlueCoat. We created a bypass rule for our client server and the handshake is now successful.

Comment: Since the server is returning the handshake failure alert: have you looked at server side logs for more information? And have you made sure that it is actually the server reacting and not some SSL termination/inspection device? You might do a packet capture at the server to verify this.

Comment: We haven't grabbed a server trace mostly because we don't own the servers we're trying to connect to. It does make sense we should verify the server is actually responding with the failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be the action of a Network Intrusion Detection System, like [snort](https://snort.org/), that has found some reason to refuse to allow one of the systems to connect.

NIDS systems work by sniffing all the packets on the network, identifying those that may be associated with suspicious behavior (such as a port scan), and then responding in some way.  By default, most NIDS will just write an alert in the log if they see something.  But your network team might have gotten more aggressive, at which point they may have enabled "active disruption".

Let's say that the failing box was used to do a network scan, and your NIDS caught it.  It would record that IP address, and every time it sees a packet on the network associated with that IP address, it sends a forged RST packet to it that looks like it came from the server's IP address.  That would prevent the machine from connecting to the server, which would certainly stop an attack.

I recommend engaging your organization's network security team, and see if they have any record of the failing machine's IP address being caught by their NIDS.

Comment: While the IDS might cause the RST I doubt that it issues the Handshake Failure alert.

Comment: If it was a NIDS, would that prevent normal TLS traffic with all destination IPs? The failing box does properly manage a handshake with many other destinations. It's just specifically one IP that it's failing with.

Comment: Because a NIDS is monitoring a specific segment of your network, it's possible that it's only seeing the traffic to the specific destination.  It certainly may not even be a NIDS; this is just one possible explanation.

Comment: We investigated the network security software and you're right. The culprit was BlueCoat preventing our handshake. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to have been of help.